# VBA: UDF summing a range of cells until nth column

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

Im a super newbie to VBA programming and I am trying to make a user defined function where I sum up a range of cells until the nth column based on LT. I know I can use the offset formula but I want to learn how to either use a for loop with this or something else.

Below is what I am trying to achieve and what I have in code. Please give your guidance.

[image]

```
Function addtill(LT As Variant, rangeA As Variant) As Variant
k = LT
  For i = 2 To 10
  For j = 3 To 12
addtill = rangeA(i, j) + rangeA(i, LT)
  Next j
  Next i
End Function
```

Comment: It isn't quite clear what this function is supposed to do and how it is supposed to be called. What is `rangeA`? what is `LT?` Why the hard-wired numbers 10 and 12? The yellow cells in your image suggest that you want to sum below the diagonal (though the pattern in the first two columns are different than the rest) but your code seems to be trying to add everything. My guess is that this UDF should be fairly easy to write, as soon what you are doing is clearly described.

Comment: One piece of advice, always put `option explicit` at the top of the module so that you dont end up with unexpected side effects from undeclared variables and unexpected type casting etc - also `k` is never used in your code above FYI.  Lastly `addtill` is continuously being overwritten `addtill = rangeA(i, j) + rangeA(i, LT)` should this be `addtill = addtil + rangeA(i, j) + rangeA(i, LT)` maybe? If you can be more clear about the functionality that would be - is it that you want to add up the lower diagonal half where `LT` is the limit? Happy to help :o)

Comment: @gass people come here for help. There is no right way to do stuff, simply opinions based on experience. I expressed my opinion about your proposal constructively and in a way that will give a newbie post maker some info to write better code and avoid common mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You may be after what follows:

```
Public Function AddTill(areaToSum As Range, LTRange As Range) As Double
    
    Dim sum As Double
    
    Dim cel As Range
        For Each cel In areaToSum .Columns(1).Cells
            sum = sum + WorksheetFunction.sum(cel.Resize(, Intersect(LTRange, cel.EntireRow)))
        Next
    
    AddTill = sum
End Function
```

the function accepts two arguments:

- `areaToSum`

  the range whose cells are to be summed up
- `LTRange`

  the range where to grab corresponding "LT" values

It loops through the `areaToSum` first column cells and keeps updating the sum with the sum of the range obtained resizing the *initial* cell to the number of columns read from the corresponding cel of `LTRange`

---

While should you need the sum row by row, you could use this function:

```
Public Function AddTill2(areaToSum As Range, LTRange As Range) As Double

    Dim cel As Range
        Set cel = Application.Caller ' get the cel the function is being called from
        AddTill2 = WorksheetFunction.sum(Intersect(areaToSum, cel.EntireRow).Resize(, Intersect(LTRange, cel.EntireRow)))

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your requirements for a UDF, you want to sum up the number of columns given by `LT` in a given range of cells. The example below may help.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function AddTill(ByVal LT As Long, ByRef area As Range) As Double
    '--- returns a sum of values from the area, starting in the
    '    first column and "adding until" the number of columns
    '    given in LT 
    '    NOTE: this function will add columns from multiple rows if
    '          the area Range has more than one row
    
    '--- if LT is greater than the number of columns in the area,
    '    then only sum the values in the area (LT would push us
    '    past the area's columns)
    Dim sumColumns As Long
    sumColumns = IIf(LT <= area.Columns.Count, LT, area.Columns.Count)
    
    Dim result As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    For i = 1 To area.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To sumColumns
            result = result + area.Cells(i, j).Value
        Next j
    Next i
    AddTill = result
End Function
```

A few important points to note:

1. [ALWAYS use `Option Explicit`](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) in your code modules.
2. Try to be clear about what the function is doing and how it's doing it. Using appropriate variable names helps quite a bit in "self-documenting" your code.
3. You used `Variant` as the types for your parameters and result. This leaves you wide open to send ANY type of value to your function (including a `String` or a `Boolean`), which is not really what you want. It's a better practice to explicitly type your parameters and all variables for what they really are. Otherwise, you will cross up different kinds of values and it's difficult to find the problem.